# How can I prevent every click on the edit button from opening a JFrame to edit the selected row?

Tags: java

I am using 2 different classes: one holding a main `JFrame` with an edit `JButton` and one holding an edit `JFrame` that is called when the button is pressed. 
First i select a row from a jtable for edit. After i press Edit button and a Jframe opens. If i press repeatedly the button, the same jframe are openning. So i want, after the first press of the button -> Jframe are openning and if i press again button I do not want to open the same frame again.
Here is a link with app image: https://ibb.co/gYfR9a

Here is my code for the Edit button:

```
JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");  
btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            Boolean chkDel = Boolean.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            if (chkDel) {
                String id = table.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                String num = table.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
                String pre = table.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
                String name = table.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
                String email = table.getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
                EditFrame f = new EditFrame(Integer.valueOf(id), num, pre, name, email);
                f.initFrame(Integer.valueOf(id), num, pre, name, email);
            }
        }
    }
});
btnEdit.setBounds(150, 250, 90, 23);
getContentPane().add(btnEdit);`
```

And here is the code for the Edit Frame:

```
public class EditFrame extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField idField;
    private JTextField numField;
    private JTextField preField;
    private JTextField nameField;
    private JTextField emailField;
    private final JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public void initFrame(int id, String num, String pre, String name, String email) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EditFrame eframe = new EditFrame(id, num, pre, name, email);
                    eframe.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: well, right now from reading the code i would say, that you open 1 frame for each row in the table where `chkDel` is true and you do that all on 1 button click

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method of your button you should memorize if it was already clicked by using a `boolean`. You can then do something like `if(!wasClickedAlready) { ... }`. However the `boolean` needs to be kept in the correct scope (one above the method). For example as **member variable** of your `ActionListener` or in the wrapping class, or something like this. Else the **state** of the `boolean` can not be memorized between **method-calls**.

For example see this snippet:

```
btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private boolean wasClicked = false;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (wasClicked) {
            // Do nothing if clicked already
            return;
        } else {
            // The button was clicked for the first time
            wasClicked = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            // Your stuff
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

If your question refers to not opening a frame for the same table row again, then you need to memorize the rows you have already clicked, for example by using a **table** of `boolean` like `boolean[]` or a `Map` mapping the row-index to a boolean like `HashMap<Integer, Boolean>`. However the scheme remains the same. If that is the case, just tell me in the comments and I will show you another snippet.

---

**Edit:** You commented that you maximally one frame should be shown for each row, not for the whole table. As stated above you can apply the same scheme than before:

```
btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private boolean[] wasClickedTable = new boolean[table.getRowCount()];

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            Boolean chkDel = Boolean.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            // A row should be processed
            if (chkDel) {
                // Lookup if row was already clicked before
                if(wasClickedTable[i]) {
                    // It was, skip the row and do not process it
                    continue;
                }
                // The row was not clicked before
                // However it is now, set it
                wasClickedTable[i] = true;                    

                // Further process the row
                // Your stuff
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes. It is about to not opening another frame for the same table row when i press the Edit button. So after i press Edit button it openes the Jframe and afther that if i press again the Edit button i want to not open again the same frame. I have memoried the rows selection in Jtable listener. The problem is that when i press Edit button a new instance are creating again and again for the same row.

Comment: it's not working...  null pointer expetion. I don't know what i do wrong :(  Maybe a solution like  :   a set list to memorize if a instance allready is open - do not open another on pressing again Jbutton

Comment: `NullPointerException`, where? How does your code look like at the moment? Please provide more input. If your question changed a lot you can also create a new question and if not you can also edit your question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly. So you have a button that opens a JFrame, but you don't want the JFrame to be opened every time the button is clicked? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: you better remove this answer as it is a comment and not an answer. other people will ask the same question

Comment: I know it's annoying, but just keep editing or answering questions you know until you get to 50 rep. Or, as it's quite difficult to get rep on StackOverflow, go to one of the other StackExchange sites until you get 200 rep for the association bonus.

Comment: First i select a row from a jtable for edit. After i press Edit button and and a Jframe opens. If i press repeatedly the button, the same jframe are openning. So i want, after first button press - Jframe  are openning and if i press again button I do not want to open the  same frame again.